# Is Kernel-Regression parametric or non-parametric?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing, parametric

As the title says, is kernel regression a parametric or non-parametric method, and how can this be motivated/explained?

Comment: What is it you want explained?  The distinction between parametric and nonparametric models?  Kernel regression?

Comment: I want to know why Kernel Regression is considered a non-parametric regression method (Wikipedia)? I heard from someone that both the case of non-parametric and parametric can be argued for Kernel Regression, which made me curious. I am sorry if the question is not clear, maybe that is because of my own lack of understanding.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  You might find material on ["semi-parametric" methods](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=semi*+parametr*+kernel+regres*+score%3A2) will illuminate some of the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kernel regression is considered non-parametric.

It is tempting to think of the amount of optimal smoothing as a "parameter", nevertheless on that aspect to quote from Shalizi's [*Advanced Data Analysis from an Elementary Point of View*](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/ADAfaEPoV/) Chapt. 4 "Using Nonparametric Smoothing in Regression": "*Strictly speaking, parameters are properties of the data-generating process
alone, so the optimal amount of smoothing is not really a parameter.*"

Our optimal amount of smoothing depends on our smoothing method, kernel choice, but also *on how much data we have*. As such as the number of data is our "parameters" in a kernel regression setting, kernel regression is non-parametric in itself. This fully aligns with the definition of a non-parametric model as a model "*that cannot be parametrized by a finite sample of parameters*" (from Wasserman's [*All of Statistics*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-21736-9) Chapt. 7 "Models, Statistical Inference and Learning").